# Is it possible to install a Linux distribution on a VM remotely?

Tags: centos, ssh, vmware-workstation

I have access to a VM with CentOS. I connect to it using "ssh".

1. I want to install Linux Kali: Can I make the installation via ssh? What would be the steps?

Thank you

Comment: Why not leave CentOS in place and install the Kali tools?